# IOS audio thread CPU usage drops when main thread use increases

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, multithreading, audio

i'm working on a IOS audio application.

I've noticed when I do lots of stuff on the main thread the cpu usage for the audio thread actually drops. With a little debugging I tracked the strange behaviour to a CADisplayLink timer were I do lots of stuff to update the UI. When I removed this method the cpu usage for the audio thread averaged around 10% but with the CADisplayLink method running the cpu usage dropped to around 5%.

As an experiment, I removed all my code in the CADisplayLink method and inserted a massive while loop just to slow down the main thread and see what would happen. The cpu usage dropped to around 5% just as before so I could confirm that it wasn't my code.

I'm testing on an iPad Pro 10.5" 2nd gen. The above doesn't seem to happen on the simulator.

Does anyone know why I am seeing this strange behaviour?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this question answered over on the Audiobus dev forum.

Looks like it's just CPU scaling. When the device has more to do, it scales up the CPU power and runs faster. Mystery solved :).